# My HTC Desire HD crashes when picking up a call. Any ideas how to resolve the problem?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calls, htc-sense, htc-desire-hd

This is extremely annoying. After the last update to Android 2.3.5, whenever I get a call from certain contacts, picking up crashes the whole phone application and resets the SIM. Rejecting the call is even worse, as the ringtone continues indefinitely and the phone blocks all input.

There is a [support thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=23181f1899e4cf53&hl=en) about this with other people having the same problem.

The solution for re-syncing all Facebook contacts didn't work for me. Has anyone here had the same problem and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried factory resetting the phone?

Comment: And erase all data? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: If you install some program that can extract your logs, for example [aLogcat](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwib3JnLmp0Yi5hbG9nY2F0Il0%2E), you may get a hint on what is crashing.

Comment: A clean start will ensure no other apps are causing the issue. However, you can try other troubleshooting steps before a wipe. Try getting the log during the crash. You can do this via ADB shell, or with an app like aLogcat, for example. Post an excerpt showing the errors here so that we can help with figuring out the issue.

Comment: doing a factory reset isn't that bad. You will not lose your contacts if they are set up to sync with your gmail account. You will lose things like "angry birds progress". You will have to reinstall your apps, if you don't have that set up to sync as well, but that might be a good thing, as one of the apps is probably causing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution for the problem, as I had the same issue.
The problem for me was when I recieved calls from people that are linked to Twitter.
When I removed the twitter-association from the contacts it worked fine.

Comment: I think this fixed it for me, although in my case it was contacts linked to Skype.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same thing but only with Skype calls - sometimes it just keeps ringing indefinitely. It doesn't lock the phone though. It seems to be worse when my 3g connection is bad or there is some sort of delay.

If it's only happening with certain contacts, try to identify what all those contacts have in common. For example, Android tries to show contacts' Facebook statuses etc when they ring - maybe it's having trouble sync'ing some piece of info like that?

Try turning off sync for certain contact types (in **Settings, Account & Sync**).